# DIV clicks using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, click

I am facing a problem with DIV clicks using JQuery.  Need advise on this issue.

I have three DIV elements in my html as follows,

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="overviewContainer">
    <div id="firstContainer"></div>
    <div id="secondContainer"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My requirement is,

1)When I click on *firstContainer*, the *secondContainer* must disappear and my *firstContainer* should expand and occupy the space of the *secondContainer*.

2)When I again click on *firstContainer*, the *secondContainer* must appear and my *firstContainer* should shrink to the original position and leave space for *secondContainer*.

For this, I have written the following jQuery code

```
$(function() {
        var firstContainerMaximized = false;
        alert("Jquery invoked");    
            $('#firstContainer').click(function(e) {
                //var firstContainerMaximized = firstContainerMaximized;
                        alert("fist container clicked");
                        if( firstContainerMaximized == false ) {
                            alert("maximizing clicked");
                            firstContainerMaximized = true;
                            $('#secondContainer').hide(); //hide the 2nd container.
                            $(this).css({ //modify the 1st container
                                "right":"1%"                    
                            });
                        } else if( firstContainerMaximized == true ) {
                            alert("minimizing clicked");
                            firstContainerMaximized == false;
                            $('#secondContainer').show(); //show the 2nd container.
                            $(this).css({ //modify the 1st container
                                "right":"49%"                   
                            });
                        }
            });

            $('#secondContainer').click(function(e) {  
                        alert("second container clicked");
                });
        });
```

The logic works for first 2 clicks.  That is, when I first click my *firstContainer*, the variable *firstContainerMaximized* was set to **FALSE** and my *firstContainer* expands as expected.

When I click on *firstContainer* 2nd time, the variable *firstContainerMaximized* was set to TRUE and my *firstContainer* shrinks as expected.

But when I click on *firstContainer* from 3rd time onwards, the variable *firstContainerMaximized* always set to **TRUE**. It is not expanding again as expected.

Kindly advise where I am going wrong here?

Is there any alternative design available to meet my requirement??

Comment: in the else if: check the second "firstContainerMaximized == false;"  it's a conditional, not setting a value

Comment: @kellycode well, you've got sharp eyes. I missed it out.. Why don't you answer?

Comment: oh.. am sorry.. Thanks kellycode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier and cleaner if you use jQuery .bind() and control the 'expanded content' by adding and removing a .class

So you would end up with something like this

HTML

```
<body>
<div id="overviewContainer">
    <div id="firstContainer">first container</div>
    <div id="secondContainer">second container</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#firstContainer{
    background: orange;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 50%;
}
#secondContainer{
    background: green;
    padding:20px;
    height: 50%;
}
#overviewContainer{
    background: red;
    height: 200px;
}
#firstContainer.maximized{
    height:100%;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#firstContainer').bind('click',function(e) {
    var $firstContainer = $(this);
    var $secondContainer = $('#secondContainer');
    var $firstContainerMaximized = $('#firstContainer.maximized');
    if( $firstContainerMaximized.length == 0 ) {                        
        $secondContainer.hide(); //hide the 2nd container.
        $firstContainer.addClass('maximized');
    } else {
        $secondContainer.show(); //show the 2nd container.
        $firstContainer.removeClass('maximized');
    }
});
$('#secondContainer').click(function(e) {  
    alert("second container clicked");
});
```

Here's also [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/leandroxbr/j12fy7tv/) with a fiddle working code. I decided to add some css to make it easier to see.

ps: The Javascript can still be simplified.

I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @kellycode, you are not using the assignment operator `=` instead you're using conditional operator `==`, which evaluates to `true` or `false`

So, change that `firstContainerMaximized == false;` to `firstContainerMaximized = false;`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are not setting the firstContainerMaximized variable properly. Correct that and it'll work.
Problem: `firstContainerMaximized == false;`
Solution: `firstContainerMaximized = false;`